# How to fix 'AuthFailureError' in volley

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I've Created an android app that fetches some texts from server and shows in list format. like Channels in Telegram.
I use a background service to check for new messages every 60 seconds on server.
everything was ok after first test of this bg-service and notification for new messages was working perfectly BUT
after 2 or 3 days, volley request always(on same device) throws AuthFailureError.

now it works on new devices but only for few days.
it seems that my server blocks the client after lots of requesting.

server is Linux-cPanel.

I've checked getHeaders method on Volley Request class:

```
@Override
public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Log.i("MYTAG", "Hey!");        

    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + DataCenter.loadToken(context));
    return headers;
}
```

But it doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 0):

after couple of days finally I've SOLVED IT.

this problem consists of two parts:

1) for some unknown reasons apache doesn't deliver 'Authorization' Header to $_SERVER;
So you have two options:

a) get headers from apache server directly:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$authHeader = $headers['Authorization'];
```

b) add this lines to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

I've used both together

2) set 'WWW-Authenticate' header only when authentication is failed.

Before:

```
<?php

header("WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm=\"example\", token_type=\"JWT\"");

if($AuthorizationResult){
    http_response_code(200);
}
else{
    http_response_code(401);
}

?>
```

After:

```
<?php

if($AuthorizationResult){
    http_response_code(200);
}
else{
    http_response_code(401);
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm=\"example\", token_type=\"JWT\"");
}

?>
```